# Can I order entries by date with sticky entries from another channel combined?

Tags: channel-entries, orderby, sorting

I'm setting up a blog page and wanted to arrange it a specific way. Blog posts would be ordered in grid format by date. But scattered throughout would be larger blocks that could link through to other outlets

I have attached an example of what I'm trying to achieve below.

[image: Layout goal]

I would only be limited to 2 channels, one for the blog posts and another for the sticky entries (larger grid items).

Obviously as blogs are posted, they would update and move around according to date ordering but I'd want the larger grid items to remain

Has anyone managed to get soemthing like this working or can anybody offer any advice on this?

Many Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: I have done something like this with Isotope.  The sorting happens in javascript instead of in EE.  Answer is out of scope for this forum so I'm just giving you the link: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: More better way to use EMBED on this. You can call your sticky channel entries in embed in middle of another channel entry loop